# Website not taking all POST Data using JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to login into a website and try to map data to see if the English to French translations are right, but for some reason, the only data it's taking is the username and password, and ignoring all language-related data.

This is what I tried:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(URL)
        .data("timezoneOffset", timeZoneOffset)
        .data("ptmode", ptMode)
        .data("ptlangcd", ptLangCD)
        .data("ptinstalledlang", ptInstalledLang)
        .data("userid", userID)
        .data("pwd", pwd)
        .data("ptlangsel", ptLangSel)
        .header("Host", HOST).userAgent(USER_AGENT)
        .header("Accept", ACCEPT)
        .header("Accept-Language", ACCEPT_LANGUAGE)
        .header("Accept-Encoding", ACCEPT_ENCODING)
        .referrer(REFERER)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();

Document document = res.parse();
System.out.println(document);
```

The first line of the HTML should return:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="fr-ca" class='firefox win pc standard'>
```

but instead it returns:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="firefox win pc standard">
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions, even hints in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without the actual address. It may well be that the post request for login does not take the other arguments into account. Maybe the server sets all variables to defaults or the values of the user preference after login.

Comment: Any possibility that "you post website url"?

Comment: I can't since the URL is private, does that make it harder to solve the question?

Comment: Yup it does. Without patient it becomes difficult to cure any the disease. But you can tak @luksch advice though.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈ ʀɛɔʘɴ All i can say about the address is that it's a [PeopleSoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeopleSoft) link.

Comment: @luksch Is it possible to work around the server issue?

Comment: We have a similar interface to this [website](https://webapp.mis.vanderbilt.edu/psp/hrprod/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG), except language selection is a dropdown menu, and when we login to the page manually with the French option selected, it shows the French interface but when we send the POST data it outputs the English interface code.

Comment: I guess that site expects one request to set the language and another request (from the same session) to do the login. It is impossible to know for sure with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Fire your favorite browser and open the Network tab in the developper toolbar.

Inspect the headers exchanged between your browser and the server.

Once done, do the same in your code.